# Lazarus RegisterFields

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I have the following code in **Delphi 7**, and I want to port to **Lazarus/FPC** (currently I'm using Lazarus 1.0.10)

```
procedure Register;
begin
    RegisterFields([TXTimeField]);
end;
```

And I got the following error:

> Error: Identifier not found "RegisterFields"

Which is the equivalent identifier for **RegisterFields** in FPC/Lazarus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a `RegisterFields` yet in Lazarus.

See [this](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=22287.0) for more information.